# three.js sparks.js

Tags: three.js, particles

everytime I try to make a render with sparks.js and Three.js, i get the same error :

Uncaught TypeError: Property '_easing' of object [object Object] is not a function sparks.js:304

Could you please tell me more? I don't understand how to fix this. Thanks.

(The tag sparks.js doesn't exist so I couldn't include it, due to my reputation, sorry).

Comment: You should post some code that causes the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is caused by using an old TWEEN constant as default value for Age action.
Try to initialise Age explicitly like :

```
new SPARKS.Age(TWEEN.Easing.Linear.None)
```